# Can ShellExecute send commands similar to Shell in Vba

Tags: excel, vba, shell, shellexecute

I have this Shell call inside a macro which gets fired when there is an Excel cell selection change.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A2000")) Is Nothing Then
Shell "C:\Program Files\CTrading\QuantShare\QuantShare.exe TaskManager ChangeSymbol newsymbol:" & ActiveCell.Value, 1
Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```

But the Shell call is not working for some programs in my system (Windows 10 Pro, Version 1909, Build 18363.476, MS Office 2013 & Office 365). Mostly, Windows 10 issue and unsolvable. Can I use ShellExecute to implement the same? Or is it that ShellExecute is only for opening a file with particular exe and cannot send additional commands inside the target programe?

Basically, this code goes inside the currently opened instance of Quantshare.exe --->Activates a plugin inside it called TaskManager and executes a script called ChangeSymbol. A variable inside that script takes the contents of the active Excel cell. In Windows Run or CMD, it executes everything.

Comment: Review http://www.suodenjoki.dk/us/productions/articles/vbashellexecute.htm

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i could use ShellExecute as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A2000")) Is Nothing Then
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
para = "TaskManager ChangeSymbol newsymbol:" & ActiveCell.Value
objShell.ShellExecute "C:\Program Files\CTrading\QuantShare\QuantShare.exe", para, "", "open", 1
Set objShell = Nothing
Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```

Can I make ShellExecute not to open a new instance of the program and rather activate the currently open instance and pass the arguments (similar to Shell)? Also how to make ShellExecute not to take focus? I want the focus to stay or come back in Excel.